# What to put into jta-data-source of persistence.xml that works on all vendors?

Tags: jpa, glassfish, websphere

Similar to [What to put into jta-data-source of persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051273/what-to-put-into-jta-data-source-of-persistence-xml) and [How to map jpa datasources in WildFly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434282/how-to-map-jpa-datasources-in-wildfly)

However, I am asking for something that would work on all vendors or at least WildFly, Glassfish/Payara, WebSphere Application Server classic, WebSphere Application Server Liberty, TomEE.  I am not looking for something that works in a Java SE Unit test.

So far I found that `java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx` works in WebSphere Application Server and TomEE.  There's a mapping exercise (which is expected) to get it working but I cannot get the same to work on GlassFish/Payara and JBoss/WildFly.

More specifically I do not wish to use default data source because for my scenario I am actually working on two different data sources. E.g. for reference data and another for transactional.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the app servers you work with are Java EE 7 compliant, you can use the default data source, which is required per EE7 spec to be available at:

```
java:comp/DefaultDataSource
```

The app server you run on ought to let you customize the configuration of the DefaultDataSource.

Since I'm familiar with WebSphere Liberty, I can point you to this doc for default data sources on Liberty:
[Configuring a default data source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_config_dds.html)

If you are using WebSphere traditional, as of v9.0 it supports Java EE 7, and has a default data source available out of the box (under the spec mandated JNDI name).

Comment: I will modify the question to be more explicit. Especiallt since I would need multiple data sources per jpa PU.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same JNDI name that works on all servers, it's best to use resource references, as explained in [What is resource-ref in web.xml used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for)

Basically, you would define an arbitrary JNDI name (ideally without any `java:comp` prefix or similar, just something like "myDatasource") and then map it to the concrete JNDI name provided by the target server.You would need to define a server-specific descriptor for each server with the mapping the if the server cannot use the JNDI directly (e.g. glassfish-web.xml for GlassFish/Payara, jboss-web.xml for WildFly, ibm-web-bnd.xml for WebSphere Classic and Liberty). TomEE seems to support references without any prefix, so it should be able to [configure a datasource](https://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html) without any additional mapping if you choose a name without a prefix.

Comment: yup that's how I got it to work with EJBs, I had to put in a dummy `    @Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/jee")
    private DataSource ds;` to make it refer to it.  There's no resource-ref on the EJB-JAR.XML top level like you do in WEB.XML

Comment: WebSphere requires the `java:comp/env` version though otherwise it will take it as the final JNDI location.  Without it it will not allow you to set the reference though the administrative console.

Comment: the `java:comp/env` prefix ought to be valid on any Java EE app server.  I believe it's mandated per spec

Comment: Both Payara and Wildfly support the DefaultDataSource using java:comp/DefaultDatasource. In other application servers, you must configure the default datasource.